# How to generate access token without any expiration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I need to get access token with expiration date as infinite.

I am using **AcquireToken** method which generates token with expiration time as 1hour based on UTC.

I need to use this access token for Add-AzureRmAccount command (Need example command for this too for successful login)

How to generate access token without any expiration in c#.

Please help me to work on this scenario.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

As Gaurav mantri mentioned that access token without any expiry is a major security risk. And it is not allowed in the Auzre. From [Configurable token lifetimes in Azure Active Directory (Public Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes) document, we could know that the default expiration of access 
token is **1 hour**, and the max is **1 day**.

Comment: In the above mentioned link i can able to check that some policy can be set for token lifetime. So cant we able to process that ?

Comment: We could set the token lifetime, but can't set the expiration of access token larger than 1 day.

Comment: Sorry, i couldn't get you. what is the difference between lifetime and expiration ? i am new to this Azure access token creation process. i couldn't understand the difference.

Comment: On my opinion, both lifetime and expiration are the same meaning.

Answer (score 2):

> How to generate access token without any expiration in c#.

Simple answer is that you can't and you shouldn't. Access tokens are returned by Azure AD and their expiration is set there only i.e. it is not in your control.

Also, getting an access token without any expiry is a major security risk (that's why "you shouldn't" remark above).

If you're using any Azure AD SDK (ADAL for example), it takes care of automatically renewing your access token so you don't have to worry about renewing that.

Comment: Agreed, except that you *can* configure the lifetime of the tokens to some extent as mention in Tom Sun's answer. You still can't make access tokens not expire of course.

Comment: Awesome answer, I'll just add that you can request a refresh token with the `offline_access` scope which is a longer lived token and can be used to silently refresh access tokens.

Comment: How to enable automatic renewal of access token? and i have some additional doubts also. 1. How to get active access token and expiry time ? 2. Is there any possible ways to get Ad username, password and client id again from access token ?

Comment: Please do not ask additional questions in comments. Either edit your question and include these additional questions there or ask a new question all together.